# My WordPress website gives me a 403 Error

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress website gives a 403 error when I try to access it, it was just fine, this error was generated overnight.

---

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

Answer (score 0):

1. deactivate all plugins. To deactivate manually see https://support.managed.com/kb/a2094/how-to-manually-disable-a-wordpress-plugin.aspx
2. backup your .htaccess file, then delete it. Generate a new .htaccess file by logging into your WordPress going to Settings -> Permalinks, and clicking Save.
3. Verify that all folders on your site have a file permission of 744 or 755 (using ftp).